# Why without 'else', it will throw java.lang.NullPointerException in preoder traversal of a BTree?

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am new to programming. My question might be dumb. (***If there is no value for others, I will delete this question later)
See these two functions here:

1.

```java
StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();
private String preorder(TreeNode root) {
        if(root == null){
          sb.append("null,");  
        } 
        sb.append(root.val);
        sb.append(",");
        String l = preorder(root.left);
        String r = preorder(root.right);

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

2.

```java
 StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();
 private String preorder(TreeNode root) {
        if(root == null){
          sb.append("null,");  
        }
        else{
            sb.append(root.val);
            sb.append(",");
            String l = preorder(root.left);
            String r = preorder(root.right);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

If I call these two functions in the main function. 
The 1st one will threw

```html
java.lang.NullPointerException error.
```

I understand that when java.lang.NullPointerException occurs:

1. when declare a variable but did not create an object

2. assign to the variable before trying to use the contents of the variable

(update on this part: 
After IF condition, regardless there is a else or no, it will execute the rest of body, thanks for everyone's help)

### (Stale. Ignore the rest of part: )

After

```java
if(root == null)
```

the rest should be

```java
root != null
```

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're wrong. The body after the `if` executes regardless of the condition.

Comment: second the above, with the caveat that if you ```return``` out of the body of the ```if``` block, then your assertion would be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

You are missing an else case.

```
private String preorder(TreeNode root) {
    if(root == null){
      sb.append("null,");  
    }else{ 
    // ... 
    }
```

The code below your if condition **will still execute** if you do not add an `else` 
or `return`.

It will throw an NPE because after your condition you 
try to access `root` with:

`sb.append(root.val);`

### Further Explanation

You need to read it like a sentence.

```
if(thisIsTrue){
  // Then do that
}else{
  // Do that
}
```

Where "thisIsTrue" is your condition. i.e `root != null`.

If you try to access a member of root with `root.val`, 
where you try to acces `val`, then root **must not be null**,
or an `NullPointerException` will be thrown.

Metaphorically speaking..imagine you have a bag of apples.
What you are trying to do, is to grap an apple, but you have no bag.

I think this is clear.

If you omit the else clause, then it will execute like the following:

```
if(thisIsTrue){
  // It will do that, if condition is true
}

// It will ALWAYS execute this, even if condition is false
```

1. **With if/else**
   You open two branches. Only **one** of them gets executed.
2. **With if, but no else**
   You have one conditional branch that gets execute if the 
   condition is true, but the code underneath will be execute **always** *afterwards*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I want to clarify what you said here:  
"It will throw an NPE because after your condition you try to access root with:
sb.append(root.val);"
After my if condition, I try to access root with sb.append(root.val)? After condition, the root != null, so it will be ok?

Comment: I tried to clarify. Does this help you to understand what is happening?

Comment: Amazing! 
Thank you very much for the explanations.
I see programs sometime only have if and no else, so this is why I was wondering. 
But your explanation makes so much sense now.